# Nested form issue, "stringify_keys"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I had problems when I was trying to integrate **Nested Form** to my rails app (rails 3.1.3, ruby 1.9.2)

First, Add **nested form** to my gemfile

```
gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
```

Then, I ran **bundle install** and followed by **rails g nested_form:install**, everything was fine so far.

I moved to next step, add **nested_form** to javascript_include_tag

```
#views/layouts/application.html.erb
javascript_include_tag "application", "nested_form"
```

Everthing still OK, I inspected HTML element and saw that **nested_form.js** was included. Then, I tried modify my form

```
#views/supplier/new.html.erb
<%= nested_form_for @supplier do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <% render "supplier_products", :f => f %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#views/supplier/_supplier_products.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :supplier_products do |supplier_product_form| %>
    <%= supplier_product_form.text_area :description %>
    <%= supplier_product_form.link_to_remove "Remove this product", supplier_product_form %>
<% end %> 

<%= f.link_to_add "Add a product", :supplier_products %>

#controller/supplier.rb
has_many :supplier_products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplier_products, :allow_destroy => true

#controller/supplier_product.rb
belongs_to :supplier
```

But then when I was trying to navigate to supplier create page, I got the following error

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "javascript:void(0)":String
```

I tried to look at my code over and over, but I couldn't see the problem. I read a lot of sites, articles and including topics from SOF, none of their solution can fix this (restart server, reinstall gem, switch ruby version and else)

So, I've no idea how to fix this. I need you guy's advise now. Please : )

**Finally**

Problem has been solved by fix the following line from

```
<% render "supplier_products", :f => f %>
```

to

```
<% render "supplier_products", :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

Comment: Did you do a search of your code where you have `javascript:void(0)` in it?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try. But, I don't think this problem will related to Javascript

Comment: It's stumbling over that in your code, so odds are it's somewhere in your code.

Comment: I was getting the same error as you, but for a different reason. You get the same error if you add a symbol after the message on link_to_remove (I copied the code from the link_to_add, ignoring that link_to_remove doesn't need that argument)